# Join itself quest

Tags: sql, join

I have table like this:

```
ID  DADOS   TIPO
1   UM  1
2   DOIS    1
3   TRES    1
4   QUATRO  1
5   CINCO   1
1   SEIS    2
```

I need to make a select that return this:

```
t1.id t1.dados t2.dados
 1     Um       Seis
 2     Dois     Null
 3     Tres     Null
 4     Quatro   Null
 5     Cinco    Null
```

I tried in this form:

```
 SELECT T1.ID, T1.DADOS, T2.DADOS
 FROM Tabela1 as T1 LEFT JOIN Tabela1  AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
 WHERE T1.TIPO = 1 AND T2.TIPO = 2
```

But the result is this:

```
ID  T1.DADOS  T2.DADOS
1   UM    SEIS
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use this code for join table itself :

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.DADOS, T2.DADOS
FROM Tabela1 as T1 LEFT JOIN Tabela1  AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
                                           And  T1.TIPO = 1 AND T2.TIPO = 2
```

also you can use this code :

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.DADOS, T2.DADOS
FROM 
  ( select * from Tabela1 T_1
    where T_1.TIPO = 1)  as T1 
  LEFT JOIN 
   (select * from Tabela1 T_2
    Where T_2.TIPO = 2)  AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Comment: Ok, but the field "Tipo" is not like ID to make a relation, the "Tipo" is the field that inform other type of data. Its like I have two tables: the first table with Tipo = 1 and the second table with Tipo = 2

Comment: ok, i edit answer , and i think the response is correct for you.

Comment: The first query you passed does not bring the expected result, but the second one is perfect. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.DADOS as T1Dados, T2.DADOS as T2Dados
FROM Tabela1 T1 
left JOIN Tabela1  T2 
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
and T1.TIPO = 1 and T2.TIPO = 2
```

See a demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7066/6

Answer (score 0):

By using the clause `WHERE T1.TIPO = 1 AND T2.TIPO = 2`, you require that a matching record are found in `T2`, and thus in reality you are turning the `left join` into an `inner join`.

In order to include the records from `T1` that have no matching record in `T2`, you can change the `where` clause to either

```
WHERE T1.TIPO = 1 AND (T2.TIPO IS NULL OR T2.TIPO = 2)
```

or

```
WHERE T1.TIPO = 1 AND T2.TIPO <> 1
```